# tikz-timing: text labels in symbols other than D, and time axis discontinuities

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-timing

This is (more-less) two (or more) questions in one - however related; so I'll try to cover all in one post. I have a specific timing diagram layout in mind, and I'm almost there:

[image: sigdisc_tikz.png]

The complete code for that example can be found below. In brief, this is what I want to achieve:

1. I want to be able to display a multi-line (two line) text label inside the `L` and `H` logic characters/symbols: the first line is the value of the signal (0 or 1) - the second line is some sort of an indexing label (which could be plainly numeric '`1`', or alphanumeric '`a1`' - passed as an argument, e.g. `h{a1}`)
2. I want to be able to show a discontinuity in the time axis; the example shows the following variants:

   1. Based on `D` character (with Low and High parallel lines; capital letter name `B` or `V`) *or* based on `Z` character (line in middle; lowercase letter name `b` or `v`)
   2. Uses ellipsis (`...`, that is, `\cdots`; `B` or `b`) *or* uses "a curvy widget" (here `$\iint$`) as separator characters (`V` or `v` metacharacter macros)

      - <sub>(sort of) off topic: I believe [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) is an appropriate character/symbol for "discontinuity" in time diagrams, as it also means "omission"; this with the "curvy widget" is something I have from back in the (high school) days (last century). *Does anyone know a name for this sort of a "curvy widget" symbol, used in the graphical/diagram sense for discontinuity/skip/omission*? I used a double integral symbol, `$\iint$`, simply because I couldn't find anything more appropriate; I simply need two parallel '`S`'-like shapes, but I don't like the [clef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clef#Other_clefs)-like "dot serifs" (*how are these called in typography*?) that the integral sign has; closest I could find is the [Unicode symbol U+2240](http://www.marathon-studios.com/unicode/U2240/Wreath_Product) '`≀`' for [wreath product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product) - however, I'd need the 'wreath' symbol rotated 180 degrees so its oriented rightly (to the right)</sub>

... and here is an overview of the problems:

1. Only `D` can accept text characters/labels 'inside' itself - this is, however, not really a problem, because in the metacharacter macro, I can first draw a `D` with thin dashed lines (*which also helps me visually - so those dashed lines in the image are on purpose*) and the text label, then 'restart' the macro drawing, and draw an `L` or `H` symbol... but, then:

   1. `D` cannot accept paragraphed content (with linebreaks) - so I have to "cheat" with TeX primitives (`\raise`/`\lower` `\hbox` and `\kern`) to simulate two lines; as a result these text lines inside are **not** center-aligned
2. I have to apply the same TeX primitive (`\raise`/`\lower` `\hbox` and `\kern`) approach, to be able to align the "time-discontinuity" symbol to the Low and High lines of the `D`-derived logic symbols (`B` and `V`); as the alignment is done "by hand", again these symbols are **not** properly center aligned (in respect to the entire width of the logic symbol)

   1. I cannot visually "interrupt" the `D` lines (if I try to "break" in code, I'll get a D transition, which I do not want) - so I have to use `\colorbox{white}{...}` to specify a white background; but then, this background "spills over" the grid, which again I do not want - I'd simply want a white "interruption" of the same height as the line

      - I'd also like the signal lines to touch exactly the "curvy widget" symbols
   2. For the `Z` derived symbols - I cannot "write" text labels "in" them, so I have to specify a "named node" (`N(b)`, `N(v)`); and then draw a TikZ text node aligned to these "named nodes" in the `\extracode` section - however, I don't want this, because I do not want to manually keep track of 'named node' references, depending on how many time discontinuities I want to show in any number of given signals

      - the ellpsis is not properly centered in this case either
      - the white background of the TikZ nodes is not as broad as in the `\colorbox` case, but I'd still like to make it as high as the signal line strokewidth only
      - Also here, I'd like the signal line to touch the "curvy widget" symbol

So, basically, those are the problems I have. I'm aware that there may not be a simple answer to these problems - however, the thing is that I (sort of) "hacked" my way through to getting this image; so, I was hoping maybe there is a more proper way of doing this, where the above problems are already handled - which I may have missed...

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

The code:

```
% sigdisc_tikz.tex
% pdflatex sigdisc_tikz.tex                                   # to obtain sigdisc_tikz.pdf
% convert -density 300x sigdisc_tikz.pdf sigdisc_tikz.png   # to obtain sigdisc_tikz.png

% \documentclass[border=0]{standalone} % incorrectly crops image - use minimal + preview
\documentclass{minimal}

% minimal doesn't have \scriptsize, \tiny:
% see also http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/ChangeFontUsingLatex ;
% copied from IEEEtran.cls (for 12 pt doc)
\makeatletter
\def\ttiny{\@setfontsize{\ttiny}{4}{5pt}}
%
\def\tiny{\@setfontsize{\tiny}{6}{7pt}}
\def\scriptsize{\@setfontsize{\scriptsize}{8}{9pt}}
\def\footnotesize{\@setfontsize{\footnotesize}{9}{10.5pt}}
\def\small{\@setfontsize{\small}{10}{12pt}}
%
\def\normalsize{\@setfontsize{\normalsize}{12}{13.92pt}}%
%
\def\large{\@setfontsize{\large}{14}{17pt}}
\def\Large{\@setfontsize{\Large}{17}{20pt}}
\def\LARGE{\@setfontsize{\LARGE}{20}{24pt}}
\def\huge{\@setfontsize{\huge}{22}{26pt}}
\def\Huge{\@setfontsize{\Huge}{24}{28pt}}

% \let\tthtext\tikztiming@handletext % ! Undefined control sequence.
% \def\tthtext{\tikztiming@handletext} % ! Improper alphabetic constant.
\makeatother



\usepackage{tikz}
% \usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,scopes,snakes,decorations.markings} % Package tikz Warning: Snakes have been superseded by decorations.
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,scopes,decorations}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary[rising arrows]{clockarrows}
\usetikztiminglibrary{advnodes}
\usetikztiminglibrary{overlays}

\usetikztiminglibrary{nicetabs} % a bit strange with \Huge; use belowrulesep to adjust
% \typeout{\the\abovetopsep} % no - belowrulesep
% \typeout{\the\belowrulesep} % yes
%% \belowrulesep=10pt % ok; but not anymore? Not with ex (1ex)?!
%% \setlength{\belowrulesep}{10ex} % ok, but not with ex/em anymore?
% use current font size in \f@size (note, it's in pt, but "without the unit"); works only for normalsize
% for others, use a new def (let):
\let\mainsize\Large
\makeatletter
{\mainsize\global\let\myfontsize\f@size}
\makeatother
\newlength{\myfontsizelen}
\setlength{\myfontsizelen}{\myfontsize pt}

\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0.4\myfontsizelen} % ok, but not with ex/em anymore?

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[graphics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\newlength{\imagewidth}
\newlength{\imagescale}

\usepackage{type1cm} % to avoid "LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <2> not available"; tlmgr install type1cm
\usepackage{helvet}

\begin{document}

% have a D with bleak color to allow text;
% then restart, and in overlay, draw a H
% \tikztimingmetachar{h}{H; O{$1$}} % nothing happens
% \tikztimingmetachar{h}{ [gray] D{1}; [black] O{H} } % all is gray
% \tikztimingmetachar{h}{ [[timing/.style={dotted,gray}]] D{1}; [black] O{H} } % all is black
% \tikztimingmetachar{h}{ [timing/.style={dotted,gray}] D{1}; [black] O{H} } % all is black
% \tikztimingmetachar{h}{ ; [dotted,gray] D{1}; [black] O{H} ; } % late?
% NOTE: `before` - O{background} - foreground - `after`
% \tikztimingmetachar{h}{ ; O{ [dotted,gray] D{1} } [solid,black] H ; } % ok
% \tikztimingmetachar{h}{ O{ [dotted,gray] D{1} } [solid,black] H  } % not ok
% \tikztimingmetachar{h}{ O{ [dotted,gray] D{1} } [solid,black] H ; } % not ok
% \tikztimingmtachar{h}{ ; O{ [dotted,gray] D{1} } [solid,black] H } % ok
% \tikztimingmetachar{h}{ ; O{ [dotted,black!10] D{1} } [solid,black] H } % ok
% \tikztimingmetachar{h}{ ; O{ [dotted,black!10,line width=1pt] D{[black]1} } [solid,black] H } % line width don't reset; default def: line width=0.15ex
% \tikztimingmetachar{h}{ ; O{ [dotted,black!10,line width=1pt] D{[black]1} } ; H } % line width, solid, black restored with the `;` before `H`

% these were OK:
% \tikztimingmetachar{h}{ ; O{ [dotted,black!40,line width=0.07ex,timing/dslope=0] D{[black]$1$} } ; H }
% \tikztimingmetachar{l}{ ; O{ [dotted,black!40,line width=0.07ex,timing/dslope=0] D{[black]$0$} } ; L }


% \linebreak inside D char has no effect;
% cannot have parbox, minipage inside D char: "Runaway argument? Paragraph ended before \tikztiming@metachar was complete."
% \parbox, \node next to D: "! Improper alphabetic constant."
% \vspace inside D passes, but no effect
% \lower1.1em\hbox{\kern-0.5em{b}} works (tex approach, as in \LaTeX logo)
% '\hbox to' does not really work there; \parbox neither ("! A <box> was supposed to be here.")
% note: #1 is always width of metacharacter
% also used: A, W, E, Q, I

% comments (code must be otherwise in one line!):
% \tikztimingmetachar{h}[2]{
%   ; % RESTART
%   O{                % start overlay
%   [dotted,black!40,line width=0.07ex,timing/dslope=0] % overlay options
%     D{                    % start D; `inside` text:
%       [black]             % option for D `inside` text
%       \parbox{2em}{       % start parbox, 2em width
%         \centering        % make stuff inside parbox centered (refers to first line)
%         $1$               % write out the value (text character) "1" in math mode
%         \lower1.1em\hbox{ % now \lower, and start a hbox
%           \kern-1.0em{    % pull the lowered content left a bit (so its almost centered with first line
%             (#2)          % write out string "(arg)"
%           }             % close \kern
%         }
%       }
%     }                 % close (insides of) D
%   }                 % close overlay
%   ; % RESTART
%   H % draw H logic character
% }

\tikztimingmetachar{h}[2]{ ; O{ [dotted,black!40,line width=0.07ex,timing/dslope=0] D{ [black] \parbox{2em}{\centering$\mathbf1$\lower1.1em\hbox{\kern-1.0em{(#2)}}}} } ; H }

\tikztimingmetachar{l}[2]{ ; O{ [dotted,black!40,line width=0.07ex,timing/dslope=0] D{ [black] \parbox{2em}{\centering$\mathbf0$\lower1.1em\hbox{\kern-1.0em{(#2)}}}} } ; L }

% "The new ‘$’ modifier can be used to calculate the width of the group characters:"
% use phantom to give an 'anchor' to \lower
% \raisebox: "! Improper alphabetic constant."
% debug with fbox:
% \tikztimingmetachar{B}[1]{ [black!40] $#1$D{\phantom{X}{\raise1.8em\hbox{\kern-1em\fbox{$\cdots$}}}{\lower1.8em\hbox{\kern-3.5em\fbox{$\cdots$}}} }  }
% with white background - colorbox
% first semicolon prevents "leak" of B's gray to the previous (say, h or l) character
% note - [red] is placed there, to show there's no effect on the color of the dots (in other position, it is simply rendered as text)
% B - based on D (...)
\tikztimingmetachar{B}[1]{ ; [black!40]$#1$D{ [red] \phantom{X}{\raise1.8em\hbox{\kern-1.3em\colorbox{white}{$\cdots$}}}{\lower1.8em\hbox{\kern-3.4em\colorbox{white}{$\cdots$}}} } }

% b - based on Z (...)
% for Z, color spec needs to be *after* the characters, to change stroke color!
% N(b) named node is to add a \node with the \cdots afterwards
\tikztimingmetachar{b}[1]{ ; $#1/2$Z[black!40] N(b) $#1/2$Z[black!40] }

% V - based on D (≀≀ / ∬ )
\tikztimingmetachar{V}[1]{ ; [black!40]$#1$D{ [red] \phantom{X}{\raise1.8em\hbox{\kern-1.3em\colorbox{white}{$\iint$}}}{\lower1.8em\hbox{\kern-3.4em\colorbox{white}{$\iint$}}} } }

% v - based on Z (≀≀ / ∬ )
\tikztimingmetachar{v}[1]{ ; $#1/2$Z[black!40] N(v) $#1/2$Z[black!40] }





%% --------------------------------

\mainsize % this one to make timing symbols (as default font) big!

\begin{tikztimingtable}[%
    timing/nodes/advanced,
    timing/dslope=0.1,
    timing/name/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize},
    timing/d/text/.style={font=\sffamily\ttiny},
  ]
  %
  % start timing diagram
  %
  \textcolor{black}{Sig1} & [black]
    Z H l{a1} l{2} h{3} 3B h{$N_{a}$} Z \\ %
  \textcolor{black}{Sig2} & [black]
    Z H h{1}  h{2} l{3} 3b l{$N_{b}$} Z \\ %
  \textcolor{black}{Sig3} & [black]
    Z H l{a1} l{2} h{3} 3V h{$N_{a}$} Z \\ %
  \textcolor{black}{Sig4} & [black]
    Z H h{1}  h{2} l{3} 3v l{$N_{b}$} Z \\ %
  %
  % end timing diagram
  %
  % there must NOT be an uncommented line before \extracode!
  %
\extracode
  % foreground:
  \tablerules
  \tablegrid
  \node[%
    rectangle,inner sep=0pt,align=center,draw=none,fill=white%
  ] at (b) {%x
    \normalsize $\cdots$%
  };
  \node[%
    rectangle,inner sep=0pt,align=center,draw=none,fill=white%
  ] at (v) {%x
    \tiny $\iint$%
  };
  % background:
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikztimingtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looking an your code, you might benefit from the `standalone` class instead of using `preview`. It saves you some extra lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use stacked material inside `D` by simply using `\shortstack{$\mathbf0$\\a1}`. There is no need to use TeX lower-level primitives for that.

Also the node character `N` also takes a content if used with `{ }` and also options using `[ ]`, i.e. `N[<options>]{<content>}`, so you can place text into the timing diagram directly, without `extracode`. By default nodes are set using the `coordinate` shape, you need to use the `rectangle` option to allow for a visible content.

I personally use dotted or dashed lines (something like `;[dashed] <chars>;`) to draw discontinuities.

BTW, allowing text content for other characters as well is on my long-term TODO list.

---

Here a way you can implement such a diagram using dotted lines and direct node content. I'm moving the node position manually to get the correct vertical position.

```
\documentclass[convert=png]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary{nicetabs} % a bit strange with \Huge; use belowrulesep to adjust

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{type1cm} % to avoid "LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <2> not available"; tlmgr install type1cm
\usepackage{helvet}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[%
    timing/dslope=0.1,
    timing/name/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize},
    timing/d/text/.style={font=\sffamily\tiny},
    grayz/.style={timing/z/.append style={gray}},
    timing/n/.style={rectangle},
    timing/metachar={{K}[2]{#1l !{++(0,+.5\yunit)} N[rectangle,scale=.3]{\shortstack{$\mathbf 0$\\(#2)}} !{++(0,-.5\yunit)} #1l}},
    timing/metachar={{J}[2]{#1h !{++(0,-.5\yunit)} N[rectangle,scale=.3]{\shortstack{$\mathbf 1$\\(#2)}} !{++(0,+.5\yunit)} #1h}},
  ]
  Sig1 & Z H K{a1} K{2} J{3} ;[gray] D;[dotted,gray] D;[gray] D; J{$N_a$} Z \\
  Sig2 & Z H J{1} J{1} K{3} ;[grayz] Z;[dotted,grayz] Z;[grayz] Z; K{$N_b$} Z \\
\extracode
  % foreground:
  \tablerules
  \tablegrid[black!25]
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @Martin Scharrer - and sorry it took forever to accept the answer (IRL took over)... Cheers!

Comment: Is there anyway to insert some text in `D` without having a transition? 
something like:
`Sig1 & Z H K{a1} K{2} J{3} ;[gray] D{text};[dotted,gray] D;[gray] D; J{$N_a$} Z` that generate the above figure. In practice using `D{text}` causes an unwanted transition.

Comment: @M.Reza: You can do this using the `overlays` library (`\usetikztiminglibrary{overlays}`): `...;[gray] O{D{text}}D;[dotted,gray] D;...`. This overlays a `D{text}` with a open right end and a normal `D`.