# CSS border-top, border-bottom, border-right LaTeX equivalent

Tags: accents, framed, japanese, css

Is there an equivalent in LaTeX to the CSS border-top, border-bottom, border-right properties?

I would like to underline and overline text with with a border on the right, not simply underline or overline it. So instead of a simple underline the text would get underlined/overlined with a border on the right.

Here's an example of what I would like to do (in CSS): http://accent.u-biq.org/english.html

I saw PDFs with such annotation before, so I'm pretty sure it can be done.

(Four tags for Google search: Japanese pitch accent annotation)

Comment: Note that this is usually called a `frame` not `border` with LaTeX. It is possible to have variants of `\fbox`, `\frame` etc. which only draw the frame rule on one or two specific sides, but I don't know any packages which provide such macros. In general you shouldn't compare HTML/CSS and LaTeX, because both use different concepts.

Comment: Frames in the `mdframed` package seem to have boolean attributes `topline`, `bottomline`, `leftline` and `rightline`. These might do the job for you. (I trust the link to the page drawn with css was only to show a picture of what you want.)  See http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf

Comment: A little more looking found this SE answer, which does indeed use `mdframed`. [How to choose which sides of the border to draw in a `framebox`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40314)

Answer (score 5):

As I already answered to the cross-post on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=20418): a quick and easy way would be to define a TikZ matrix for the characters, where each character is a node which can be referred to, for drawing such a path.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes]{
    A & B & C & D & E\\};
  \draw (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-1.north east) -- (m-1-1.south east)
    -- (m-1-2.south west) -- (m-1-2.south east) -- (m-1-2.north east)
    -- (m-1-5.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: path around symbols]

Comment: +1 for TikZ. Using [tikz-timing would be overkill](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37278/2975).

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to have variants of `\fbox`, `\frame` etc. which only draw the frame rule on one or two specific sides, but I don't know any packages which provide such macros.

I took the standard LaTeX `\fbox` definition and added color support and an optional argument which can be used to select the sides with a frame: `l` left, `b` bottom, `r` right and `t` top. The line thickness can be changed using the `\fboxrule` length and the separation between the content and the frame using `\fboxsep`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\cfbox[3][lbrt]{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
    \color@begingroup
      \kern\fboxsep{#3}\kern\fboxsep
    \color@endgroup
  }%
  \@tempdima\fboxrule
  \advance\@tempdima\fboxsep
  \advance\@tempdima\dp\@tempboxa
  \hbox{%
    \hskip-.5\fboxrule
    \lower\@tempdima\hbox{%
      \vbox{%
        \in@{t}{#1}%
        \ifin@
            {\color{#2}%
            \hrule\@height\fboxrule
            }%
        \fi
        \hbox{%
          \in@{l}{#1}%
          \ifin@
            {\color{#2}%
            \vrule\@width\fboxrule
            }%
          \fi
          \vbox{%
            \vskip\fboxsep
            \box\@tempboxa
            \vskip\fboxsep}%
          \in@{r}{#1}%
          \ifin@
            {\color{#2}%
            \vrule\@width\fboxrule
            }%
          \fi
        }%
        \in@{b}{#1}%
        \ifin@
          {\color{#2}%
          \hrule\@height\fboxrule
          }%
        \fi
      }%
    }%
    \hskip-.5\fboxrule
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cfbox[l]{red}{A}%
\cfbox[b]{red}{B}%
\cfbox[r]{red}{C}%
\cfbox[t]{red}{D}%

\bigskip


\setlength{\fboxsep}{.2ex}
\cfbox[b]{red}{AB}%
\cfbox[ltr]{red}{C}%
\cfbox[b]{red}{D}%

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: PS: I'm using the helpful macro `\in@` from the LaTeX kernel here. See [`macros2e`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/macros2e) and [`source2e`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/source2e).

Comment: Thank you for that! I prefer this method to the one by Stefan, as I can have a script automate my text easier.

Comment: @Phil: No problem, using TikZ is indeed easier for this specific case. I posted this solution more as a programming exercise.