# How to add y-label in tikz-timing graph?

Tags: tikz-timing

MWE

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[
scale=2.5,
timing/slope=0.1,
timing/rowdist=3ex
]
\textnormal{Clock} & [black] 4{hz} \\
\extracode
 \begin{background}
 \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=1 pt] at (0,1){\tiny k};
 \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=1 pt] at (0,.5){\tiny o};
 \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=1 pt] at (0,0){\tiny c};
 \end{background}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\vertlines[help lines]{0,1,3,4}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\tablegrid
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

And that I want output,

[image]

How to add (center) **k**, **o**, and **c**?

Related to: [tikz-timing: text labels in symbols other than D, and time axis discontinuities](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37254/tikz-timing-text-labels-in-symbols-other-than-d-and-time-axis-discontinuities)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good evening,

the timingtable provides labels for all rows starting with row 1 (page 15 of the [tikz-timing.pdf](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-timing/tikz-timing.pdf)). Therefore you can place the nodes along the west side of row1.

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[
scale=2.5,
timing/slope=0.1,
timing/rowdist=3ex
]
\textnormal{Clock} & [black] 4{hz} \\
\extracode
 \begin{background}
 %\node[anchor=south east,inner sep=1 pt] at (0,1){\tiny k};
 %\node[anchor=south east,inner sep=1 pt] at (0,.5){\tiny o};
 %\node[anchor=south east,inner sep=1 pt] at (0,0){\tiny c};
 \node[anchor=east] at (row1.north west){\tiny k};
 \node[anchor=east] at (row1.west){\tiny o};
 \node[anchor=east] at (row1.south west){\tiny c};
 \end{background}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\vertlines[help lines]{0,1,3,4}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\tablegrid
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

The Position of your nodes can be tweaked with the `xshift` parameter.

Cheers!

Comment: Perfect working, @Richard.